# Meteor: unreliable session variable?

Tags: session, meteor

I'm making a service where there are no user accounts, and I want to restrict by what page I'm visiting.

So each page is a "box", and on each "box" I have a bunch of "files".

I've published the relevant info in server/publications.coffee

```
Meteor.publish 'files', (boxId)->
  console.log boxId
  return Files.find({boxId:boxId})
```

My file for 'box' has a subscription handle:

```
@filesHandle = Meteor.subscribe 'files', Session.get('currentBoxId')
```

And the currentBoxId is stored in the session variable.

Here's the crazy part: I expect this to work, and it does on the first time I start the server. The console.log in the first bit of code prints the proper ID. Then, all of a sudden the console log suddenly starts returning "null", even when I console.log the session var in the browser console, it returns correctly.

I feel like there's some kind of loading asynchrony issue here, but I have no idea what's going on.

Any clues?

Comment: Bear in mind the Meteor Session does not persist between page refreshes, don't expect the value to be retained if you Ctrl+R in the browser. See http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance#.UlHsaBCc5pg

Comment: Holy crap, you're right. Suddenly, I have no idea why the code I wrote is working. When I refresh, the session variable isn't retained, but the relevant data is still retrieved! Do you have any idea how this could be possible? Here's the relevant code...Template.boxPage.created = ()->
  @filesHandle = Meteor.subscribe 'files', Session.get('currentBoxId')

Comment: Wait, upon further examination, it seems like my session variable does persist across page refreshes. Did Meteor change the way it handles sessions?

Comment: If you Ctrl+R your Session is cleared, but if you do a 'hot code push' i.e. change the code and the browser is refreshed for you, the Session is retained (this difference has tripped me up a few times looking for a bug which turned out to be an error between keyboard and chair) ;) I've also seen some packages around (can't remember their names) which use localStorage to try and maintain the session, so maybe you have one of those in your project.

Comment: @BobDavies that was an excellent fact to point out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out. The template can be rendered before the session variable is set, apparently. Usually you put your collection handles in the main.js file in the application scope, but this doesn't work if the subscription depends on session variables.

I did the following:

```
Template.boxPage.created = ()->
  @filesHandle = Meteor.subscribe 'files', Session.get('currentBoxId')
```